# How I can plot multiple roc together?

Tags: modeling, glm, roc

I want to find some good predictors (genes). This is my data, log transformed RNA-seq:

```
          TRG    CDK6 EGFR  KIF2C CDC20
Sample 1  TRG12  11.39 10.62  9.75 10.34
Sample 2  TRG12  10.16  8.63  8.68  9.08
Sample 3  TRG12   9.29 10.24  9.89 10.11
Sample 4  TRG45  11.53  9.22  9.35  9.13
Sample 5  TRG45   8.35 10.62 10.25 10.01
Sample 6  TRG45  11.71 10.43  8.87  9.44
```

I have calculated confusion matrix for different models like below

1- I tested each of 23 genes individually in this code and each of them gives p-value < 0.05 remained as a good predictor; For example for CDK6 I have done

```
glm=glm(TRG ~ CDK6, data = df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

Finally I obtained five genes and I put them in this model:

```
final <- glm(TRG ~ CDK6 + CXCL8 + IL6 + ISG15 + PTGS2 , data = df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

I want a plot like this for ROC curve of each model but I don't know how to do that

[image]

Any help please?

Comment: You cannot build a ROC curve from a confusion matrix. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274974/36682. What data do you have?

Comment: Thank you so much I have made models I have edited my question with more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you an answer using the pROC package. Disclaimer: I am the author and maintiner of the package. There are alternative ways to do it.

The plot your are seeing was probably generated by the [`ggroc`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.14.0/topics/ggroc.roc) function of pROC. In order to generate such a plot from glm models, you need to 1) use the `predict` function to generate the predictions, 2) generate the roc curves and store them in a list, preferably named to get a legend automatically, and 3) call `ggroc`.

```
glm.cdk6 <- glm(TRG ~ CDK6, data = df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
final <- glm(TRG ~ CDK6 + CXCL8 + IL6 + ISG15 + PTGS2 , data = df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))

rocs <- list()

library(pROC)
rocs[["CDK6"]] <- roc(df$TRG, predict(glm.cdk6))
rocs[["final"]] <- roc(df$TRG, predict(final))

ggroc(rocs)
```